# If vs. while in specific JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

Why does the author of *Test-Driven JavaScript Development* (Christian Johansen) use the `while` statement instead of the `if` statement in the code below?

```
function getEventTarget(event) {
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

    while (target && target.nodeType != 1) {
        target = target.parentNode;
    }

    return target;
}
```

Comment: You do realize that `while` is a loop, right? It will execute over and over until the condition becomes false.

Answer (score 9):

Because the author wanted to keep walking up the tree until the correct node type was found; it might not be the immediate parent.

However, in this case it makes no sense, as `parentNode` will always return an element in real-world usage (or a Document).

Answer (score 0):

**Because he is walking up..**

If you see pretty well, in the loop he is assigning the target again with its parent and the parent is not nodetype 1

```
 target = target.parentNode;
```

I don't know what is he trying or what is the purpose or the goal but it's quite simple..

Imagine the DOM

```
<div>
  <div>
     <div>
        <div>
           Imagine he starts from here.. he will always get the max parent with not nodetype 1 the hightes parent so the first div..
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SO basically. He is getting the **Higher** parent ... That's why is he looping.. if uses the If.. he will get just the **First** parent

Comment: But `nodeType==1` is an element node, so as soon as you walk out of the TextNode (in the unlikely case that it fired the event) you have an element.

Comment: It keeps walking as long as `nodeType!=1`, which means that it stops as soon as `nodeType==1`, which it will always do either immediately or after one iteration.

Comment: Yes my mystake, you are right, BUT i think he did it for something look at this example http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/nodetype.shtml